# Вставка текста в несколько полей

Tags: javascript, jquery

На сайте есть три поля input: имя, пароль, ящик. Скопировал текст из Excel (например), который содержится одной строкой, но с разделителем "запятая". Как сделать так, чтобы при вставке текста в первое поле, если найдена запятая, оставшийся текст вставляется во второе поле, ну и далее в третье?

С вставкой текста "по клику", можно не заморачиваться))

Comment: т.е всегда разделитель будет запятой ?

Comment: да, всегда запятая.

Comment: и всегда сначала вставляется в первое поле ?

Comment: да, всегда только в первое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если правильно понял вопрос, то можно сделать так. Вставьте в первый инпут вашу строку, например, "Вася Пупкин,password,email".

```js
$('form input').first().on('input', function() {
  var str = $(this).val();
  str = str.split(',');
  $('form input').each(function(index) {
    $(this).val(str[index]);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
  <input type="text" name="password" /><br />
  <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
</form>
```

Comment: Отлично! То, что нужно было!

Comment: @user260846 если убрать .first(), будет работать при вставке в любой из инпутов.

Answer (score 1):

Вот простой пример по `JQuery` но при условии что и последовательность данных в каждой строке будет всегда одна....
ЗЫ: я думаю, при вашей логике получения данный, у вас всегда будут проблемы если пользователь захочет что то изменить в вставленном тексте... данные могу удалиться!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#name').on('change',function(){
var data = $(this).val().trim().split(',');
if(data[0] != ''){
$('#name').val(data[0]);
}

if(data[1] != ''){
$('#pass').val(data[1]);
}

if(data[2] != ''){
$('#email').val(data[2]);
}

});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name"><br>
<input type="password" id="pass"><br>
<input type="email" id="email"><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вставьте строку с 2 запятыми
правда только через ctrl+v

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Пример веб-страницы</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <label>Name<input type="text" id="firstInput"></label>
     <label>Pasword<input type="text" id="secondInput"></label>
     <label>Mail<input type="text" id="thirdInput"></label>
 </body>
    <script>
        'use scrict';
        firstInput.onkeyup = function(e){
            if(e.keyCode != 86) return;
            let string = firstInput.value,
                stringAreAready = false;
            firstInput.value = string.substring(0, string.indexOf(','));
            string = string.substring(string.indexOf(',') + 1);
            secondInput.value = string.substring(0, string.indexOf(','));
            string = string.substring(string.indexOf(',') + 1);
            thirdInput.value = string;
        };
    </script>
</html>
```